# How i can edit the css file using php?

Tags: php

I created custom.css file Manually and I want to add some css like below programmatically using PHP

```
 .test{
    color:red;
}
```

For example i have one button If i click that button i want to add the css to css file

Comment: Use javascript for adding CSS at runtime. That is not possible which you want to do.

Comment: @404BrainNotFound I don't see OP mentioning the word `runtime` anywhere. This actually can be done in several ways, you could write some web based CSS editor that is able to edit your css file or you could add a php handler to css files, this way the php interpreter is able to parse php inside css files

Comment: Ohh my bad @DarkBee  I forgot to see `want to include some CSS`. I thought he wants to add some CSS code into his CSS file by some PHP code, that's y I wrote runtime. For OP's question, the answer is correct of @user2486.

Comment: sorry i edit my question please check

Comment: Do you want that the CSS persists or what? It's confusing now.

Comment: i want to add css to css file programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript/jQuery to add styles for the elements. To update the css file with new styles then you have to use FILE concepts to open a file, read and write(append) the content of the existing file. But those styles will not apply in your html views(i mean to say in browser run time).

So by adding through Javascript/jQuery to for the elements is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<style>.style {width: 100%;}</style>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, let's say that you already have a HTML file which includes your custom.css file. Let's say that you have a paragraph in your html file that you want to color red, in case of some condition. To do that, you can simply echo the CSS class name if the condition satisfies, like this:

```
<?php
$condition = true;
?>
<p class="$condition ? 'test' : ''">Test text</p>
```

If you wonder how to include custom.css file in HTML in the first place, you can check out this article: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp. You can also do it conditialy. For, example, using the link tag which will point to your custom.css file:

```
<?php
$condition = true;
if ($condition) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">';
}
?>
```

If you actually want to write to a custom.css file directly (add content to it), you can use [file_put_contents PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: sorry i want to add css to css file programmatically